# How can I see changesets that remove a match *in a specific branch*?

Tags: mercurial

As `hg help grep` says:

> By default, grep prints the most recent revision number for each file in
>       which it finds a match. To get it to print every revision that contains a
>       change in match status ("-" for a match that becomes a non-match, or "+"
>       for a non-match that becomes a match), use the --all flag.

This works as advertised: When I run `hg grep --all pattern`, I get a list of hits marked with `:+:` or `:-:`:

```
plaintext.py:8055:+:  ...
plaintext.py:4690:-:  ...
otherfile.py:4690:-:  ...
plaintext.py:4630:+:  ...
plaintext.py:4630:+:  ...
```

The problem is when I try to **restrict the search to a branch or revset:**

```
hg grep --all -r 'branch(default)' pattern
```

The above will no longer print the revisions in which there is a change of status.  Lots of revisions that match are printed (not just the most recent or most ancient one), and many revisions that removed a match (marked with `:-:`) are no longer printed. (Some `:-:`-revisions are still printed; I don't understand when this happens.)

This seems like it could be a bug, but what do I know. I'm using mercurial 4.2 (on OS X).

I could live with filtering the output of unrestricted `hg grep --all`; but the default format does not include the branch (and I do know know enough to write a template that includes all the current information plus the branch).

Comment: Are you 100% percent sure that the revisions that removed a match and are not displayed anymore are on the default branch? If so, it looks like a bug.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check. It looks like a bug/misfeature to me either way, since adding a revset range should give a subset of the unrestricted results, and it most certainly doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into this bug:

https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3885

Unfortunately "hg grep" is notoriously buggy and likely needs lots of work to get into a place where it's more usable.

Comment: That's the one, indeed! It's a bit worrisome that the commenters in the bug report don't even understand that it's a bug, or what it should be doing...

Comment: I hadn't chanced upon the information that hg grep is "notoriously buggy", thanks. I'll have to use it even less...